# FTP upload and download greyed out in Netbeans 8.0.1

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Only since yesterday have we seen this happen (maybe related to yesterdays OS X Java Update?) Only certain folders have the options disabled.  Some projects are unaffected, others allow us to upload from the root directory then choose a file but other projects have no FTP facility at all.

This has occurred simultaneously on 2 MacBook's with OSX Yosemite, both with latest Netbeans and recently updated to Java 1.7.0_71

Not seen this before, is anyone else experiencing similar problems?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Noticed when upgraded to Netbeans 8.1 I couldn't Upload/Download in some projects. This is the solution that worked for me:

In the first folder I couldn't Upload/Download, I had a **file .json** (in my case, composer.json). I **renamed this file** to .composer.json and **restarted Netbeans**. Then, I could Upload/Download without problems.

I hope it's a Netbeans version bug and it will be solved soon, but meanwhile, you can continue uploading files to your server through Netbeans.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

HaHa!  Problem solved.

The nbproject folder was the offending article.  I simply deleted that folder.  I think this was accidentally added to the Git repo by someone in the office who shall remain nameless ;-)

Comment: Ultimately, this was our issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved for me,

1 - Delete your nbProject folder

2 - close your project and reopen it

3 - configure your project by clicking right -> properties

Enjoy !

Comment: close then open the project solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Came across this post because I was having the same issue where Upload, Delete and Synchronize options in the file's right-click menu was grayed out.

Our situation was a little different where I had our souce files syncing between two computers with separate Netbeans installs, using Microsoft OneDrive. Even though both computers had their nbproject paths set to separate external directories from the source code path, both set ups had their upload/download options disabled.

Come to find out the old nbproject directory in the source path was confusing something in NetBeans. Closing netbeans, renaming the folder and re-opening Netbeans fixed the issue.